# Roblox: clone an object in all players backpack lua

Tags: lua, roblox

So I made this code:

```
local players = game.Players:getPlayers()
local drink = game.ServerStorage.Drink:Clone()
CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(steven_Image,"Eat while it's hot!")
drink.Parent = game.Players.Backpack
```

To put in all players backpack `Drink` but it's not working :/ no error in output so any idea how can I fix it? thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to give it to the players currently in the server, you could just loop through them:

```lua
local players = game.Players:getPlayers()
CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(steven_Image,"Eat while it's hot!")
for _, player in pairs(players) do
    local drink = game.ServerStorage.Drink:Clone()
    drink.Parent = player.Backpack
end
```

If you want to give it to all of the players right when they join the game, put it in the `StarterPack` and *presto* it will be in everyone's backpack.